# How do I reference a non-SQL CLR project from my SQL CLR project?

Tags: c#, sql, teamcity, sqlclr

I have a solution with two projects.  The first is a basic class library project containing the definition of classes shared between several service endpoints (DataContract.dll).  The second is a SQL CLR project that will use the classes defined in the shared assembly.  On my local machine I can register this assembly with local instance of SQL Server, add a reference to the assembly, and compile.  However, when I commit this code to our build machine the assembly is not registered on the server.  I could manually register the assembly on the build server, but this won't help new developers who join the project and have a broken build on their first check-out.  Also, our build server chooses a random name for the temporary directory it builds in, so the reference on the build server's database instance may be stale or missing.  Is there any way to reference the shared library project from my SQL CLR project such that the build server and new developers will always have a good build?

Comment: Perhaps my setup differs from yours, but in my SQLCLR project, the only references I can add come from the database targeted for deployment. Seems to me the build server needs to be configured the same way. If that's not possible, seems registering the class assembly in the GAC of the build machine is the only choice.

Comment: Yes, that is the restriction I'm trying to work around (shared assembly must be registered with a DB accessible both by my development machine and the build machine, or the assembly must be in the GAC of the machine performing the compile).  The build machine is clearing out the previous build (and thus invalidating the current GAC / DB registration) then rebuilding in a new location. This results in a missing reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue before though it was not necessarily just SQLCLR.  I found that the best way to do this was to [create my own NuGet server](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).  If this seems to complicated or you don't have the resources then I would suggest having just a unc share for libs that are shared.  You can create a post build script that copies the binaries to the unc path after successfully compiling them locally.